# Spring security: My Authorization filter authorizes my request even tho the URL is permited

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In my security configuration class i have permitted the request to the welcome url and any other url which follows the "welcome/**" format.

this is my securityconfiguration class:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
//@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class JwtSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    private final CustomerDetailsService customerDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    public JwtSecurityConfiguration(CustomerDetailsService customerDetailsService) {

        this.customerDetailsService = customerDetailsService;
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(customerDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoderBean());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoderBean() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }



    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web.ignoring().antMatchers("**/resources/static/**")
                .and()
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js",
                        "/index_assets/**"
                );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/welcome/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/welcome/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("admin/rest/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        //http.addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

         http.addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(),customerDetailsService),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // disable page caching
        http
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()  // required to set for H2 else H2 Console will be blank.
                .cacheControl();

        //http.headers().cacheControl();

    }
}
```

but I noticed that in my JWTAuthorizationFilter.class the doFilterInternal() method picks up this URL

```
public class JWTAuthorizationFilter  extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final CustomerDetailsService customerDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    DefaultCookieService defaultCookieService;


    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, CustomerDetailsService customerDetailsService) {

       // super(authenticationManager);

        this.customerDetailsService = customerDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String header = request.getHeader(HEADER);

        if(Objects.isNull(header) || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)){


            return;


        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuth = getAuthenticationToken(request);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuth);

        chain.doFilter(request,response);

    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthenticationToken(HttpServletRequest request){

        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER);

        if(Objects.isNull(token)) return null;

        String username = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET)
                .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX,""))
                .getBody()
                .getSubject();


        UserDetails userDetails = customerDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        return username != null ? new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()) : null;
    }
}
```

What is the cause of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter is suppose to pick up each and every request. It doesn't matter if that you have permitted or not in security configuration.

You have got two options:

1. If you don't want `welcome/**` to go through the filter you add it to web ignore

   ```
   @Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

       web.ignoring().antMatchers("**/resources/static/**")
               .and()
               .ignoring()
               .antMatchers(
                       HttpMethod.GET,
                       "/",
                       "/*.html",
                       "/favicon.ico",
                       "/**/*.html",
                       "/**/*.css",
                       "/**/*.js",
                       "/index_assets/**",
                       "/welcome/**"
               );
   }
   ```

But note, it will skip all filters and you may not want that.

2. In `doFilterInternal` method skip it when you find `welcome/**` pattern.

Comment: i am curious, if filters pick up all urls, then why is there a .permitAll() method

Comment: two things: 1) `.permitAll()` doesn't mean it will skip all the filter. 2) `JWTAuthorizationFilter` is your custom filter. How would Spring know to skip it when you explicitly said to apply it before `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

Comment: `@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)` try this annotation and see in console what are the list of filters applied to each request. It might help clear some of the things.